# Customer Adresses rest api - add created_at

Tags: magento2, customer, address

I need to return on the webservice **/rest/V1/customers/** the created_at and updated_at fields from the table *customer_address_entity*. Any help?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create extension attributes. Please follow below links for the reference:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html